# Group-specific parameter estimation with non-linear least squares regression

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, nonlinear-regression

I am generating several groups of observations (*x,y*), in which the non-linear relationship between *x* and *y* is dependent on a group-specific parameter (*random*) as well as a constant parameter (*fixed*) that does not vary between groups:

*y = random * (|x|+1)^(-fixed)*

I would like to retrieve the values of these parameters given the generated data. In the example below, this data includes 100 (*x,y*) observations for each of three groups ("A", "B" or "C"), derived using *random* parameter values of 22, 33 and 99, respectively and a *fixed* value of 0.8:

```
nonlinear = function(x, random, fixed){
  random * (abs(x)+1)^(-1*fixed)
}

data = data.frame(x=rep(1:100,times=3),
                  y=c(nonlinear(x=1:100,random=22,fixed=0.8),
                      nonlinear(x=1:100,random=33,fixed=0.8),
                      nonlinear(x=1:100,random=99,fixed=0.8)),
                  group=as.factor(rep(LETTERS[1:3],each=100)))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=x, y=y, color=group)) + geom_point() + geom_line()

nls(y~nonlinear(x,random,fixed),
    data=data,
    start=list(random=1,fixed=1))

library(nlme)
nlme(y~nonlinear(x,random,fixed),
     data=data,
     fixed=fixed~1,
     random=random~1,
     groups=~group,
     start=c(random=1, fixed=1))
```

[image: sample data]

With R's nls(), I can only retrieve a single value of *fixed* (the correct constant) and a single (incorrect) value of *random*, as grouping information is not considered by this function.

How would I go about finding a constant value for *fixed* across all groups and a group-specific estimates of the *random* parameter? I tried specifying a mixed effects model with nlme(), but got the following error:

```
Error in nlme.formula(y ~ nonlinear(x, random, fixed), data = data, fixed = fixed ~  : 
  starting values for the 'fixed' component are not the correct length
```

Any suggestion would be much appreciated.